# Sitecore Commerce Connect > Refreshing a Cache via code

Tags: sitecore, sitecore8, sitecore-commerce-server

I am trying to update the commerce catalog from external source. After the incremental update I need to have fresh data in Sitecore tree(data provider should return correct data instead of old(cached) ones). However, if I go to Sitecore right after the data import I can see only the old data till I click on ["Refresh Catalog Cache"](http://screencast.com/t/ZKTYf8btq) button in Sitecore Commerce menu.

I found [the same info](http://commercesdn.sitecore.net/SCpbCS81/SitecoreCommerceConnectGuide/en-us/#Task/t_DroppingaCache.html) in the documentation for Sitecore Commerce Connect, however I can't find any example how to clean cache via code.

I found several types in "Sitecore.Commerce.Connect.CommerceServer.Caching" namespace. For example, CacheRefresh static class. It has RefreshCatalogCaches method which needs ICommerceServerContextManager contextManager as input parameter. If I create contextManager just using constructor new CommerceServerContextManager() and passing it to the method - it doesn't work(at least I still need to clean cache manually).

I would appreciate any advise/suggestion.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should do in your code same that happens on "Refresh Catalog Cache" button click:

```
CacheRefreshEvent eventX = new CacheRefreshEvent("catalogcache", "master", = ID.Null);
EventManager.QueueEvent<CacheRefreshEvent>(eventX, true, true);
```

For more details, look on `Sitecore.Commerce.Connect.CommerceServer.Caching.RefreshCache, Sitecore.Commerce.Connect.CommerceServer` implementation via reflector.